# Segmentation fault while updating an 2D array

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, structure

I'm working on 2D arrays and pointers and I'm trying to create a crossword puzzle. I'm a newbie on C so still confused about pointer and arrays. In this code I'm trying to insert words from struct array to 2D array. When I'm debugging my code inserts(I hope it does) 2 words to the array but in the 3rd one I get segmentation fault.

My struct:

```
typedef struct
{
 char *word;     //word and corresponding hint
 char *clues;
 int x;      //Starting x and y positions
 int y;
 char direction;     //H for horizontal, V for vertical
 int f;      //solved or not
}Word_t;
```

What I'm trying to do is reading the direction of the word and insert the appropriate place on my 2D array. Likely:

```
*****
*****
*****  //first state of the array
*****
*****

//insert a word like "MILK whose direction is 'H' x=1 y=1"

MILK*
*****
*****
*****
*****
```

My function to insert strings to the board:

```
char** updateBoard(char** myBoard, Word_t *nWords, int solve)
{
if(solve!=-1)
{
    if(nWords[solve].direction=='V')
    {
        int len=strlen(nWords[solve].word);
        for(int i=0;i<=len;i++)
        {
            myBoard[nWords[solve].y][i]=nWords[solve].word[i];
        }
    }
    else if(nWords[solve].direction=='H')
    {
        int len=strlen(nWords[solve].word);
        for(int i=0;i<=len;i++)
        {
            myBoard[nWords[solve].x][i]=nWords[solve].word[i];     //segmentation fault here
        }
    }
}
else{
    if(nWords[solve].direction=='V')
    {
        int len=strlen(nWords[solve].word);
        for(int i=0;i<=len;i++)
        {
            myBoard[nWords[solve].y][i]='_';
        }
    }
    else if(nWords[solve].direction=='H')
    {
        int len=strlen(nWords[solve].word);
        for(int i=0;i<=len;i++)
        {
            myBoard[nWords[solve].x][i]='_';
        }
    }
}
return myBoard;
}
```

Comment: Please provide [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your problem is likely in *nul-termination* (or lack there of) in `nWords`, etc.. Remember a pointer is simply a variable that holds the *address of* something else as its value. In other words, a pointer *points to* the address where something else can be found. For example, while `int a = 5;` stores the immediate value `5` as its value, `int *b;` creates a pointer to `int`, and `b = &a;` stores the address of `a` (the memory address where `5` is currectly stored) as its value.

Comment: it seems overflow, can you update with trace ?

Comment: when you are debugging your program (I presume you **are debugging** and not just asking us to do the debugging for you, right?) - what is the value you get for `len` in this statement: `int len=strlen(nWords[solve].word);`?

Comment: when the execution gets to `else{
    if(nWords[solve].direction=='V')`  the value in 'solve' is -1   This means the code is trying to access some memory BEFORE the beginning of the array: `nWords[]`   That is undefined behavior. Then any values read from memory would be garbage.

Comment: Is there some prior executed code that ensures that the value in `.direction` is either `V` or `H`?  If so, then some of the `else { if` statements can be removed

Comment: The posted code does not compile!  Are you expecting us to guess as to the contents of the passed in parameters?  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.  3)

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
typedef struct
{
    char *word;     //word and corresponding hint
    char *clues;
    int x;      //Starting x and y positions
    int y;
    char direction;     //H for horizontal, V for vertical
    int f;      //solved or not
}Word_t;
```

and

```
myBoard[nWords[solve].x][i]=nWords[solve].word[i];
```

the field: `word` is a pointer.  That pointer has not been set to point to some memory that the application owns (via `malloc()` or `calloc()`)

So the application is writing where ever the trash in the field `word` happens to point.   This is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault 
event.

What is the actual definition of `myBoard[][]?

what are the value(s) in the instance of `Word_t nWord[ source ]` when the failure occurs?